# How to import own data set for training GAN

Tags: python, generative-adversarial-network

In the application of GAN, we saw so many people use MNIST and Cifar10 dataset because those dataset have split into training data and testing data.

[image]

While most of our situation is that we may need to use our data .
like my dataset's training path is :
'/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/original data/positive'
then how can I import them and should I split my data into train set or test set?
all my dataset are smile faces and I want to generate more smile face through GAN.

Any ideas or github project for shareing?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that GAN is not CNN or RNN, it does not have any task like classification (I mean ordinary GAN). It contains a *Discriminator* and a *Generator*, which means the *D* will use images synthesized from *G* and take it as input together with the original images in your training set. In this way *G* is trained to synthesize more realistic images.

Therefore, you do not need to separate your dataset into training / testing set -- not for GAN in this situation.

To import your own data instead of using data that is already in the library, I suggest using `flow_from_directory()` if you are using keras/tensorflow.

You can refer to the documentation [here](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#flowfromdirectory-method).

EDIT: Or directly using `load_img(directory)` for individual images. The documentation is the same one as above.